# Character limitation in regular expression won't work

Tags: regex

I want to check the string if it obeys these rules:

- **First part:** 2 digits
- 1 space
- **Second part:** Capital letters. 1, 2 or 3 characters
- 1 space
- **Third part:** 2, 3 or 4 digits

My regular expression:

```
/\d{2}\s.[A-Z]{1,3}\s.\d{2,4}/
```

It works with most strings but it doesn't with some like these:

- 134 HY 723 (It shouldn't allow 3 digits in first part)
- 34 H 723 (It should allow one letter in second part)
- 34 HD 723435 (It shouldn't allow over 4 digits in third part)

Comment: What is the `.` there for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this one:

```
/^\d{2}\s[A-Z]{1,3}\s\d{2,4}$/
```

You were missing the anchors (`^` and `$`). Your original one would match, say, `134 HY 723`, by matching `34 HY 723`.

I also removed two random `.`s. (I have no idea why they were there)